# Second concurrent page method call not working

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-7, pagemethods

I have two page method calls that I perform. One is a long request that performs alot of processing. The second one is used to retrieve the status of the first call. The problem is that the second call doesn't get a response until the first one has ended. Looking at fiddler, I see that the first page method call sends a request followed by the second page method sending a request back to back but I never get the second request in visual studio until the first ends. I thought ie7 allowed 2 concurrent requests at a time.